# Selenium - page never loads on windows server

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, windows-server-2012

I am running selenium webdriver using eclipse and firefox.
I needed to deploy and run it on a windows Server.
so I followed those steps:

1. exported an executable jar
2. create a run.bat which does it: `java.exe -jar SeleniumTestAutomation.jar`
3. runned it

the problem is that the gecko driver gets to run firefox but it never seems to load the home page of my test case, as below:

[image]

here is the console message:

```
1516381435343   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1516381435343   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:2703
1516381436031   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Fi
les\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\srvadm\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4\\rust_mozprofile.3hIE5DahwYIE"
1516381436531   Marionette      INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\srvadm\AppData\Local\openvr\openvr
paths.vrpath
[Parent 8272, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/
ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\srvadm\AppData\Local\openvr\openvr
paths.vrpath
[Child 8540, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/s
rc/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 8540, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/s
rc/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1516381437997   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 53261
1516381438108   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored f
or this session
1516381438164   Marionette      DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 42949672
97
Jan 19, 2018 5:03:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSessi
on
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

please why is this happening and how to fix it?

here is the code of my test case:

```
        Log.startTestCase(tc);

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");

 ...
            Log.info("recupera il driver del browser");
            String urlHp = "https://www.gewiss.com/ww/it";
            // vai su url da testare
            driver.get(urlHp);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // click su contatti
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='topbar']/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]")).click();
            // bottone inviaci un messaggio
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/a")).click();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.info("Exception: " + e.getClass() + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.endTestCase(tc);
```

It works perfectly on Windows 10.

on windows Server this is the firefox version:  57.0.4 (64 bit)

Comment: I don't see any error as such, you are all fine with `INFO: Detected dialect: W3C`

Comment: check the Firefox and geckodriver version on Windows server are same as on Windows 10. Or make sure the Firefox and geckodriver on Windows server are compatible at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by installing geckodriver on the Windows Server, hope it will help someone in future from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.